# Testing values rendered with the CSS Calc function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

I'm testing a progress bar with React Testing Library and I want to check that the inner bar corresponds to the expected fraction of the outer bar.

By using `getComputedStyle` I can reconstruct the interpolated value that I'm expecting, but I'd like to **decouple the testing logic from the implementation** by testing the final rendering.

So **I'd like to know if I can check the actual value in pixel computed by the `calc` function**.

`jsx`

```
<span data-testid="progress-bg">
  <span progress={ progress } data-testid="progress-fg"/>
</span>
```

`css`

```
--bar-width: 100%;
.progress-bg {
  width: --bar-width
}
.progress-fg {
  width: `calc(var(-barWidth) * ${progress})` // progress set using css-in-js
}
```

`test`

```
const backgroundBar = screen.getByTestId("progress-bg");
const backgroundBarWidth = getComputedStyle(backgroundBar).width;

const foregroundBar = screen.getByTestId("progress-fg");
const foregroundBarWidth = getComputedStyle(foregroundBar).width;

expect(foregroundBarWidth)
  .toEqual(`calc(${backgroundBarWidth} * ${progress})`);
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

You would have to use the `getComputedStyle` function to check. The styles are complied by the browser's rendering engine. Through `react-testing-library`, it uses JSDOM's rendering engine, which `getComputedStyle` is part of.

Keep in mind that JSDOM rendering for styles may differ from actual computed styles as it depends on the browser engine and layout of element.