# How to test the CSS calc() function?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, testing

I'm building a page with multiple configurations, where the `style` of the root `div` has the CSS `calc` function to its `grid` values.

For each change I make, I need to verify that nothing broke for many values, which would be great to have in an automatic test.

What are the ways to test and verify the correctness of my values after the `calc` function?

For example, I would like to do something like:

```js
test("div grid", () => {
  expect(createMyDivComponent(...values)).toBe({ gridTemplateRows: "20px 20px" })
})
```

Where the `20px` values are after the execution of the `calc` function.

Comment: What is 'the root div'?

Comment: the first div after the body. for the test case, it doesn't really matter, think of it as just a single div

Comment: I was trying to see whether CSS variables were set all over the place or in the one element. I think showing us some typical code might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing values rendered with the CSS Calc function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75918418/testing-values-rendered-with-the-css-calc-function)